# How to use a GUI developed with C# or Java in Unity 3d

Tags: java, c#, user-interface, 3d

I have beginned to learn Unity 3d. And I know, there are GUI-Components build in in Unity 3d.

But I want to developed an "external" GUI with C# or Java, and use this GUI to change the parameter such as "speed" "position" and so on. How can I integrate the GUI into a Unity 3d project? Is that possible?

With best regards and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why don't you just build the GUI in Unity3D using C#?

Comment: you mean using the build-in Component in unity?

Comment: I just want to create another GUI based on C#, to start the game and send parameter to initial the game.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a powerful GUI in Unity5 now, which uses C# or javascript in the background.

Here is a [link](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) to some tutorials to get you started, however it is not like their old GUI system.

Answer (score 0):

Unity uses its own GUI system/UI system, there are a lot of tutorials online how to use it.

*Yes* it is possible to use C# to change the GUI while the game is running.

One thing that you want to keep in mind is when you create a script that will need to use the UI namespace.

That means that at the top of the script you have to put: `using UnityEngine.UI;`.
some good tutorial links:

- [-Brackys-Healthbar tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLfNP4Sc_iA&feature=emb_rel_end) -Understand the core of the unity UI.
- [-BlackThornProd- How to make UI in UNITY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RIsfVOqTaE) - EASY TUTORIAL
- [-GameDevGuide- How to make your UI look good!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwdweCX5aMI) - Builds on what you have learned before.